# How to set up a reminder like every fourth Wednesday?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar, reminder

How to set up a reminder like every fourth Wednesday? Preferably in Outlook or Google Calendar?

Answer (score 5):

[image: Google Calendar]Google calendar provides a repeat checkbox for every event you create.  You can select this and edit the frequency.  The relevant sections in the calendar entry are circled in red in the attached image.  After your selections are complete you can confirm your selection by checking the summary section.

And here's what you need to do on Outlook.  This example shows an appointment but you can use the same settings to set up a recurring meeting.
[image: Outlook Appointment]

Answer (score 2):

When creating an event in Google Calendar, you have to option for repeat.  Set that to `Weekly`, set the next option `Repeat every 4 weeks`, set the next option to `Repeat on Wednesday`, and done.  Change days, weeks, etc as needed.  Wash, Rinse, Repeat.