# How to create recurring reminders in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks, reminder

I want to create a follow-up/task with a reminder which will remind me this follow-up/task at 10th of each month, the reminder should pop-up a window and play a sound at 10th of each month, just like in regular "follow-up"s. How can I do this in Outlook 2010?

Comment: Take a look at this:http://superuser.com/questions/527843/how-to-set-up-a-reminder-like-every-fourth-wednesday

Comment: What have you tried? There are recurrence settings specifically for this. If you tried something and it didn't work, tell us so we can help you. As it is, your question is too vague and shows little effort on your part.

Answer (score 9):

Create Task to have recurrence reminders on 10th of every month. Follow the simple steps and screenshot to achieve this.

Press Ctrl+Shift+K to open a "New Task" window > Enter the reminder information's such as Subject, Priority and etc. Now, click on 'Recurrence' > select 'Monthly' > enter 10 on the 'Day' field and save it. For more information's, please refer the screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: After pressing okay you can set the date & time for the reminder. The reminder time will be updated to the same time for the following week, after you complete the task in the current week.

Comment: In case you have assigned the task to somebody else, you need to click "Task" Ribbon, "Tag" section, "Follow up". There you can choose "Add reminders...".